# &Amp; - what is it, and what does it signify?

Tags: email

What does "&Amp;" mean / signify?

Comment: its an ampersand

Comment: Could just about salvage the question and get it above character minimum limits!

Answer (score 1):

it's what's called an "html entity" (https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_entities.asp) 
since html is (sort of) a programming language it uses some symbols as code

for example - html tags look like this: `<div>` but what if you wanted to also type < as text?

html has this built in replacements to some "special characters" this particular one replaces the char &.

one would ask - "why would I replace & with `&amp;` ? it already has & in it!"
- but that's exactly why you need this! since & is used in all "html entities"

I hope you understand now!

Answer (score 0):

`&` is HTML for "Start of a character reference".

`&amp;` is the character reference for "An ampersand".

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ampersand